# how to stretch image using pyqt4 style sheet?

Tags: stylesheet, pyqt4

I have a widget that i want to have a background image. I've  try using background-size but its not working. I know it could be done in qlabel but i want to know if its possible for pyqt4 style sheet. Is there a way to stretch the image depending on  the widget's size?

```
QWidget#widget{
    image: url(:/images/image.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `border-image`.

```
QWidget#widget{
    border-image: url(:/images/image.jpg);
}
```

Quoting from the [docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/stylesheet-customizing.html):

> A background-image does not scale with the size of the widget. To
>   provide a "skin" or background that scales along with the widget size,
>   one must use border-image. Since the border-image property provides an
>   alternate background, it is not required to specify a background-image
>   when border-image is specified. In the case, when both of them are
>   specified, the border-image draws over the background-image.